# Removing ambiguity of overloaded method definition

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, overloading, ambiguous

The compiler is getting confused by an overloaded method definiton and I cannot find a way to clarify my intention sufficiently.

I have the following code:

`val part: (QueryParams) => List[ResultMap] = (partOf.find _).andThen(makeMap)`

The `find` method is overloaded:

```
def find(params: QueryParams): List[U] = ...
def find(params: QueryParams, flattener: U => T): List[T] = ...
```

The code was working fine as long as there was a single definiton of `find`. Since I had to add the second `find` definiton with 2 params, the compiler is generating this error:

`Error:(15, 31) ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method find in trait DataFetcher of type (params: ...QueryParams)List[...Parser]
and  method find in trait DataFetcher of type (params: ...QueryParams, flattener: ...Parser => ...ResultTuple)List[...ResultTuple]
match expected type ?
  val part: Fetcher = (partOf.find _).andThen(makeMap)
                              ^`

IMHO there is no ambiguity. The type of `part` is defined to accept one argument of type `QueryParams`. There is only one method accepting a single `QueryParams`. `U` and `T` are different types and `makeMap` expects a `List[U]` There are no implicits, default values or varargs involved.

Is there a way to further clarify my intention to the compiler?

**EDIT**: one way to remove the ambiguity is to introduce an intermediary value, clarifying the expected type of the eta expansion:

```
val find: (QueryParams) => List[ResultTuple] = partOf.find _
val part: (QueryParams) => List[ResultMap] = find andThen makeMap
```

But since `makeMap` is only accepting `List[ResultTuple]` I stil dont get the reason for the supposed ambiguity and would prefer not to introduce the extra value. Any clarification?

Answer (score 2):

First, it is important to understand that the trailing underscore is a deliberate design decision to prevent [programmer mistakes](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html#8.7). The only exception is when the type is explicitly declared.

Here is an example illustrating this point.

```
object A {
  def add(a: Int)(b:Int): Int = a + b
  val x: Int => Int = add(5) // compiles fine
  val y = add(5) // produces a compiler error
}
```

The same applies to your question. Because you do not specify the intermediate type, when you write `find _`, should the compiler infer the type to be `QueryParams => List[ResultTuple]` (as you may expect) or should it be `(QueryParams, U => T) => List[ResultTuple]`? Note that the trailing underscore does not stand for a single argument, it just lifts the method to a function. When the type if declared, you can drop the trailing underscore and write `find` where you would have written `find _`.

I see from your edit that you found out that an intermediate value with a declared type works. Another (slightly clunky) way to clarify your intent is the following.

```
val part: (QueryParams) => List[ResultMap] = (x => partOf.find(x)).andThen(makeMap)
```

Comment: +1 Yeah, the lambda with args variant works as well, thanks for the tip, moem. If the compiler error is deliberate, I would have expected for it to nudge me into the right direction, but I fail to see what design principle it is about. It would be cool if the ambiguity could be resolved by somehow providing the type of the method to be extended - a clumsy version `find[QueryParams]: List[ResultTuple] _`

Comment: @kostja Because you do not specify the intermediate type, when you write `find _`, should the compiler infer the type to be `QueryParams => List[ResultTuple]` (as you may expect) or should it be `(QueryParams, U => T) => List[ResultTuple]`? Note that the trailing underscore does not stand for a single argument, it just lifts the method to a function.